# Capturing React Diffs and patching them manually

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom, react-dom

Does React/react-dom have the ability to let users manually compare two doms, get the diff, and apply the diff to the dom manually?

As it happens now, it seems like the process of diffing and patching is done internally but I am hoping to do it seperately.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way currently to do this. Not really sure why you would need React if you were to do reconciliation on your own. As you mention, this is done internally. You could probably fork [`react`](https://github.com/facebook/react) and change the way it does diffs, or maybe even expose an external API to let developers do their own diffs if they want.

React is pretty good at what it does, and it unlikely you will do better. See the [Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) and [Advanced Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) sections for more on how React does diffs.

Now, what you can do within a React component is specify a [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) method and tell each component if it should update (and thus possibly have to reconcile) the DOM. This is actually recommended to improve performance if your components are pure based on props/state.

Comment: Bummer.  I'm trying to calculate a "diff", do somethings to the html, and then apply my altered diff to a copy of the original non-diffed dom.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to dynamically change where the app renders to, and then you could compare the previously previous render with the new one